# Kubernetes pod giving 400 when internal ip is used

Tags: kubernetes

**After doing exec on the pod**

The following request is giving **200**

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
```

When the private IP of the same pod is used as the host it is giving **400** (bad request)

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://10.18.41.289:8000/'
```

Shouldn't the behavior should be the same when the pod's internal ip is used instead of localhost from the pod?

Comment: Does that request use redirection? Try without --location

Comment: It is giving 400 without --location also

Comment: Can you also add the pod yaml? and perhaps add `-vvv` to the curl request and put the output into your post as well